# How to proxy http_x_ssl_client_s_dn header?

Tags: proxy, nginx

I want to proxy the request header 'HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN' through nginx.

Here is our server network structure.

```
[front server:443] <---> [nginx proxy:8004] <---> [application server:8008]
(client cert auth)
```

When I tried it two servers([front server] and [application server]), it worked properly. The header 'HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN' was passed to application server.

Then adding the server [nginx proxy], the header 'HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN' was not passed to application server.

My nginx config is below.

```
server {
    listen   8004;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_pass_header X-Scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://app-server/;

# TODO: to proxy 'HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'
# failed settings
#        proxy_pass_request_headers on; # not worked (default: on)
#        proxy_pass_header X-SSL-Client-S-DN; # none
#        proxy_pass_header X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN; # none
#        proxy_pass_header HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN; # none
#        proxy_pass_header HTTP-X-SSL-CLIENT-S-DN; # none
#        proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-S-DN $ssl_client_s_dn; # none
#        proxy_set_header X_SSL_Client_S_DN $x_ssl_client_s_dn; # none
#        proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-S-DN $http_ssl_client_s_dn; # none
#        proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-S-DN $http_x_ssl_client_s_dn; # none
    }
}

upstream app-server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8008;
}
```

Any help appliciated.

Answer (score 7):

First and foremost, make sure you have nginx.conf configured to verify client certificates!  I had exact same problem you described.

```
server {
  # ...
  ssl_client_certificate /srv/ssl/self.crt;
  ssl_verify_depth     1;
  ssl_verify_client    on;
  # ...
  location @app { # I'm using nginx+unicorn, don't blindly copy this!  :)
    # ...
    proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Serial $ssl_client_serial;
    proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-Verify $ssl_client_verify;
    proxy_set_header X-SSL-Client-S-DN   $ssl_client_s_dn;
    # ...
}
```

To test this out, you will need a separate client key and a certificate that has been signed using the root authority certificate.  The client credentials start with "me" and my root authority credentials start with "self" in the following commands.

1. Generate a private key for the client.

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out me.key 1024
   ```
2. Make a request for the self-CA to sign.

   ```
   openssl req -new -key me.key -out me.csr
   ```
3. Sign the request using the self-CA to create a certificate.

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in me.csr -CA self.crt -CAkey self.key -set_serial 01 -out me.crt
   ```
4. Try out your new key.

   ```
   curl -v -s -k --key me.key --cert me.crt https://fort-awesome-o
   ```
5. Extra credit: generate a certificate that can be imported into your browser.

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in me.crt -inkey me.key -certfile self.crt -out me.p12
   ```

I have a simple Sinatra web app that dumps the HTTP environment and I see the following:

"HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_SERIAL"=>"01", "HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY"=>"SUCCESS", "HTTP_X_SSL_CLIENT_S_DN"=>"/C=US/ST=Maryland/L=Annapolis/O=Fort Kickass/CN=Jonathan Morton/emailAddress=jon@jonmorton.com"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with nginx as proxy deleted the `X_REQUESTED_WITH` field from the request. Per default nginx marks headers with underscores as invalid and ignores invalid headers.

You can use nginx directives to either allow underscores in headers with `underscores_in_headers on;` or don't ignore invalid header with `ignore_invalid_headers off;`.

In my concrete case I used python requests as client, django as server and nginx as proxy and solved my problem in which I renamed `X_REQUESTED_WITH` to `X-REQUESTED-WITH`. (Django automatically adds `'HTTP_'` to the start of x-header names before making the header available in `request.META.`)

```
import requests
headers = {'X-REQUESTED-WITH':'XMLHttpRequest'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks eli_mach. Your suggestion has value to try. I'll try your suggestion lator, but I have lost my testing environment.